# How can I install postgresql-client on a Debian docker image

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm writing a shell script that will use pg_dump and pg_restore and I want everything to run in a Docker image. I have a hard time installing the postgres-client when building my Docker image. I do it like that:

```
RUN apt update && apt -y install postgresql-client
```

I feel it is a simple question but I can't find the answer on the net :-(

Comment: What errors / problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was a stupid one, my docker image was based on Alpine and not Debian. So the answer is:

```
RUN apk add && apk add postgresql-client
```

Comment: that pulls v13. how do you install version 15?